# 'ValueChanging' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement a handler, in React, for a survey implemented in SurveyJS. This is for multiple-choice questions that may have answers like "None of the Above" or "Prefer Not To Answer". If one of those answers is selected, all other answers should be blanked out, and if a different answer is selected, these checkboxes should be cleared out. I'm doing fine with either one of these individually, but having problems with a question where both options are present, specifically when switching back & forth between the two special options.

What I think is happening is that when one answer triggers the handler, and unchecks the other checkbox, it triggers the handler again. My solution is to set a state that indicates when the handler is in the middle of this process, and not do it again at that time.

I got a JS solution for this here: https://github.com/surveyjs/editor/issues/125 - and below is my attempt to convert it to React. (Just the relevant parts of the code included.)

However, on compile, it gives the following error:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Survey/SurveyContainer.tsx:55:19
>   TS2339: Property 'ValueChanging' does not exist on type
>   'Readonly<{}>'.

I can't find anything about this specific error. Other references to the state (i.e. where I'm setting it) are working. Why can't I read it?

Thanks!

Component:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { Survey, surveyStrings } from 'survey-react';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import Marked from '../Marked';
import * as style from './style';

interface Props {
  surveyJson: object;
  complete: boolean;
  resultMarkdown: string;
  surveyTitle: string;
  sendSurveyAnswers: (answers: object[]) => void;
  noneOfTheAboveHandler: (survey: object, options: object) => void;
}

Survey.cssType = 'standard';
surveyStrings.progressText = '{0}/{1}';
surveyStrings.emptySurvey = '';

export default class SurveyComponent extends Component<Props, {}> {
  render() {
    const { surveyJson, sendSurveyAnswers, complete, surveyTitle, resultMarkdown, noneOfTheAboveHandler } = this.props;
    return (
      <style.Wrapper>
         { surveyJson && (!complete) &&
          <style.SurveyWrapper>
            <style.SurveyTitle>{ surveyTitle }</style.SurveyTitle>
            <style.Survey>
              <Survey
                onValueChanged={ noneOfTheAboveHandler }
                css={ style.surveyStyles }
                json={ surveyJson }
                onComplete={ sendSurveyAnswers }
              />
            </style.Survey>
          </style.SurveyWrapper>
         }
         { complete &&
         <style.Results>
           <Marked content={resultMarkdown} />
         </style.Results>
         }
      </style.Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Container:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import SurveyComponent from './SurveyComponent';

interface Props {
  id: string;
  surveyJson: object;
  complete: boolean;
  resultMarkdown: string;
  surveyTitle: string;
  getSurveyQuestions: (id: string) => void;
  sendSurveyAnswers: (answers: object[]) => void;
  noneOfTheAboveHandler: (survey: object, options: object) => void;
  clearSurvey: () => void;
}

class SurveyContainer extends Component<Props, {}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ValueChanging: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.noneOfTheAboveHandler = this.noneOfTheAboveHandler.bind(this);
    this.props.getSurveyQuestions(this.props.id);
  }

  specialValueSelected(options, specialValue) {
    const { question } = options;
    const prevValue = question.prevValue;
    const index = options.value.indexOf(specialValue);
    this.setState({ ValueChanging: true });
    //has special value selected
    if(index > -1) {
      //special value was selected before
      if(prevValue.indexOf(specialValue) > -1) {
        var value = question.value;
        value.splice(index, 1);
        question.value = value;
      } else {
        //special value select just now
        question.value = [specialValue];
      }
    }
    this.setState({ ValueChanging: false });
    return index > -1;
  }

  noneOfTheAboveHandler(survey, options) {
    const none = 'NA';
    const preferNotToAnswer = 'PN';
    const { question } = options;

    if(this.state.ValueChanging) {
      return;
    }

    if (!question || question.getType() !== 'checkbox') {
      return;
    }

    if (!question.prevValue || !options.value) {
      question.prevValue = options.value;
      return;
    }

    if (!this.specialValueSelected(options,none)) {
      this.specialValueSelected(options,preferNotToAnswer);
    }

    question.prevValue = options.value;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.clearSurvey();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SurveyComponent
        noneOfTheAboveHandler={this.noneOfTheAboveHandler}
        {...this.props}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  surveyJson: state.survey.json,
  answers: state.survey.answers,
  resultMarkdown: state.survey.resultMarkdown,
  complete: state.survey.complete,
  surveyTitle: state.page && state.page.data ? state.page.data.title : ''
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getSurveyQuestions: id => dispatch({ type: 'GET_SURVEY_QUESTIONS', id }),
  sendSurveyAnswers: answers => dispatch({ type: 'SEND_SURVEY_ANSWERS', answers: answers.data }),
  clearSurvey: () => dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_SURVEY' })
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SurveyContainer);
```

Comment: How are you unchecking the other checkboxes?

Comment: It should not be that hard and lengthier. May be if you can post your component, We can work out a smaller and easier way out

Comment: When I set question.value for a question, it becomes the complete list of answers. (e.g. if I set it to "NA", then only the "NA" checkbox is checked, and all other checkboxes are unchecked.) I'll post the full component.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The most likely cause for this is that you don't specify the type for your component's state in its class definition, so it defaults to `{}`. You can fix it by declaring interfaces for the types of props and state and providing these as type arguments to React.Component:

```
interface MyComponentProps { /* declare your component's props here */ }
interface MyComponentState { ValueChanging :  boolean }

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {
  constructor(props) {
  ...
```

You could provide the types directly between the `<` and `>`, but using interfaces usually leads to more readable code and promotes reuse. To prevent confusion with components it's also a good idea to use lower-case identifiers for the properties on props and state.

Comment: Got past the compile issues, thanks! Still some logic debugging to do, but I can take it from there. :)

Answer (score 0):

FYI: We have introduce this functionality into SurveyJS Library sometimes ago.

Here is [the react example](https://codesandbox.io/s/qlw8rp1mlw) with "Select All" and "None of the Above" features, out of the box, without custom code.

Thank you!