# Can't access object property even though type of returns it is an object - React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React state which is array of objects and I am adding an object to it in setState method. The objects adds correctly.

Now when I try to access the object in some other function, I can't access the property of object. I can see on console that the object exists with the properties. I checked other similar questions on stackoverflow which are related to asynchronous calls but mine does not fall under that.

I have created array of object like this,

```
interface ResultState{
....
localArray : object[];
}
```

Initializing it to null in constructor.

And adding an object to it like,

```
localArray : this.state.localArray.concat(Items1)
```

My console output :

```
localArray -> [{}]
              0:
                 name: 'abcd'
                 roll_num: 10
                 address: [{...}]
                     0: {Street:  'abcdefgh', aptnum: 1}
```

Now I want to access address of the object.
My code is like this,

```
const resultObject = this.state.localArray[0];
return resultObject.address;
```

But I get an error property address does not exist on type object.

when I do console.log(typeof(resultObject)), comes object.

what could possibly the reason for this?

Comment: What is the output of `JSON.stringify(this.state.localArray[0])`? I am not sure, but I think some browsers log the reference to the object, so when the object gets modified after logging, it also modifies the logged value

Comment: The output comes like this, {"name":"abcd","roll_num":10,"address":"..."}

Comment: Just to be sure: This gets logged right before assigning `resultObject`? And it's the same as the logging of `JSON.stringify(resultObject)`?

Comment: yes, to both. I am logging it before assigng resultObject and stringify of resultObject is also the same.

Comment: For `localArray: object[]` are you actually using the type "object"? Make sure whatever type object is it has an address field define. If you don't have a type try `localArray: any[]`

Comment: Ah, I thought it was a runtime error. For the react state in typescript I guess this question will help: [Using state in react with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987816/using-state-in-react-with-typescript/46987987)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad you got it working, but using type `any[]` isn't great because it says that your array could contain anything.  What you really want is for typescript to know the type of the specific objects in your array.  Based on what you've posted, it should be something like:

```
interface Address {
    Street: string;
    aptnum: number;
}

interface Entry {
    name: string;
    roll_num: number;
    address: Address[];
}

interface ResultState {
    ....
    localArray: Entry[];
}
```

That way typescript knows that your array elements are objects, but it also knows what properties are valid and what the types are for each property.

Comment: But the problem is this Object is coming from api call and the json structure can have number of variations. So what should be done in this case?

Comment: Do you know which of the variations you're going to get when you make the call?  If so, you would use generics to define the type at the time of the call.  If you don't know what the response looks like until you see it, you would use what's called a discriminated union.

Comment: The other way to think about is "what's the minimum that I need right now for this function?"  Rather than typing the whole response, just type the parts that you are using.  You are accessing `resultObject.address` so you expect that every object in your array has an `address` property or else this doesn't make sense.  So you can say `localArray: {address: Address[]}[]` It's fine if the object has more than just that property, but there will be and should be errors if you can't be sure that the objects contain that property. The point of typescript errors is to avoid potential runtime errors.

Comment: Yeah my `address` definition is going to change depending on some criteria. There will be 5 variations. So may be I can use generics in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was because of the type of the array. After changing it to `localArray: any[]`, it worked!