# Type 'string' is not assignable to type ' undefined'

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have one React Component in which I am using useState hook.
I tried to set value to general onClick of menu item.

```js
const [value,setValue]= useState("");

<Menu.Item onClick={()=>setValue("general"))>

</Menu.Item>
```

In another file I am passing that value.

```js
<ChannelForm
   value={value}
/>
```

I am using TypeScript. Have declared prop type definition as

```js
value?: "general" | "competitive" | "social" | "podcast";
```

But while passing value as a props I am getting above error.

Comment: Can we have the full code of your component ? It looks like you are misunderstanding the role of state and props which are different

Comment: This props type definition of value is in ChannelForm Component. In channelForm component I am passing value as a props.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify - are you using an interface? See this question: [Using state in react with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987816/using-state-in-react-with-typescript/46987987), for more on that.

If that doesn't help, the problem could be typescript thinks it's being passed a null value. To fix that you can use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator). Read more about that in this answer: [Typescript: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496398/typescript-type-string-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-string)

If neither of those helps, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the "?" from value so this won't be optional:

```
value: "general" | "competitive" | "social" | "podcast";
```

and in state initialization you should use a default value e.g. "general":

```
const [value,setValue]= useState("general");
```